# php script error within html file

Tags: php

i'm relatively new to this trying to get a mysql database array of Username to be shown in a html drop down input for another form however the php script just keep being shown rather than the function. below is a screenshot of the error

http://s10.postimage.org/j4xuamkwp/untitled.png

the php script is sat within my html file

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$db = 'fid';

$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass);
if (!$conn)
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($db);

echo '<label class="input" for="investigator" type="input">Importance:</label><select id="investigator" name="investigator">';
$resource = mysql_query("SELECT `Username` FROM `user`");
if($resource && mysql_num_rows($resource)) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resource)){
        echo '<option value="'.$row['Username'].'">'.$row['Username'].'</option>';
    }
}
echo '</select>';
mysql_close($conn)
?>
```

I think its an issue within the while loop however cannot fix it and its getting very frustrating!

Comment: your server won't parse files with .html extension as php. you either need to add php handler to it using htaccess or apache conf, or change extension of the file

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file needs to have a `.php` extension to work properly.

`.html` will not be recognized as a php file.

Name your file: myfile.php for files that have php code in them. NOT myfile.html

EDIT: As others have pointed out, you can add html as a php type, but that's not typically how it's done, nor would I recommend it.

Comment: Hm.. true but not entirely. You can run .html as .php by using `AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm`

Comment: nah not true can tell server to use .bla file like php

Comment: Thank you i new it would be something small affecting it problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your server isn't parsing PHP properly.  Couple troubleshooting tips-

1) make sure you're PHP is enabled on the server.
2) make sure the extension of your file is ".php".
3) If you would like your server to parse ".htm|html" files as PHP, you can change your .htaccess (assuming you are using apache), by [following these steps.](http://www.velvetblues.com/web-development-blog/how-to-parse-html-files-as-php/)

Answer (score 0):

Yep, `.html` will not be read by the PHP interpreter (the part of the web server that reads and computes PHP scripts).

If you rename your file with a `.php` ending, for example `file.php` (**not** `file.html`) your script should work.

This part of your script has me confused:

```
if (!$conn)
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
```

Should it not be

```
if (!$conn) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

The `{` and `}` tells `PHP` which part of your script is `if` or `while` and which parts aren't.

Comment: In php, a single line (and only a single line) below an if/else statement does not require curly braces.